# Google Sheets GS - Sort interval if date (column 1) matches

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple code that auto sorts the 1st column by date (ascending):

```
function classificaAuto() {
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var folha = planilha.getSheets()[0];
  var intervalo = folha.getRange('A4:H');
  intervalo.sort({column:1, ascending:true});
}
```

Now, I would like to sort (ascending) intervals from B:H that have the same date from column A. How could I do that?

For example, from the sheet below, I would like that it auto-sort B206:H211, then auto-sort B213:H221, and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for multiple level data sorting. You can just include an array of the columns you want to sort by in your `sort` function, per the [Google Apps Script docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)):

```
intervalo.sort([{column:1, ascending:true}, {column:2, ascending:true}]);
```

Or if they are all ascending, simply:

```
intervalo.sort([1, 2]);
```

Comment: That did it! Didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks a lot!